# The name 'WebMail' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The following code works fine locally, but when I publish it to the server, I get the error The name 'WebMail' does not exist in the current context. Not sure why this occurs especially if it works locally. Thanks for any help.

```
public void SendMessage()
        {
            WebMail.SmtpServer = SmtpServer;
            WebMail.UserName = ServerUsername;
            WebMail.Password = ServerPassword;
            WebMail.From = this.From;
            var recipents = string.Join(",", this.To);
            WebMail.Send(recipents, this.Subject, this.Body);
        }
```

Comment: Go hit F12 on `WebMail` and see exactly what namespace and DLL it's in.  Make sure that DLL is deployed and/or GAC'ed on your server.

Comment: System.Web.Helpers, since its in system.web it should be on the server

Comment: although not likely to be the problem, try adding it explicitly to the web.config.  I don't remember the circumstances that trigger the problem, but I've seen the problem where code in a code behind on server throws an exception and starts working when added to the web.config.  (Probably not the issue, but could be worth checking.)

Comment: I made sure that <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces> was added

Comment: Did you install asp.net mvc on your server or at least the required .dlls e.g. *System.Web.Helpers.dll*? http://blog.discountasp.net/getting-asp-net-mvc-3-working-on-discountasp-net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. The publish in VS 2012 was not adding the helper.dll. Added it and now works! Thanks for all the advice.